# How can I set the mouse sensivity / speed in embedded qt?

Tags: qt, mouse

I am running a embedded application which uses QT. Sometimes the mouse speed is either too slow / too fast.

How can I adjust it?

Comment: which OS is your embedded system running?

Comment: It's running the Linux kernel. The system architecture is i386. My qt application uses the Linux framebuffer by using a QWSServer. So there's no way to set it in X or so.